# How to get value of radio in datalist?

Tags: asp.net, sql, radio-button

I have a data list like this :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="3"
        onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rd_CS" runat="server" GroupName="Casi" 
                         oncheckedchanged="rd_CS_CheckedChanged" Text='<%# Eval("Key")%>'></asp:RadioButton>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="Img_Nhacsi" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Hinhanh")%>' Width="75px"
                            Height="75px" BorderColor="#66FF33" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Ten" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Ngaysinh" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Birthdate")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Country")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
    </asp:DataList>
```

I got a button submit in page. How to get the text of checked radio button when i click submit button ? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need something like this (Credit goes to [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa)):

```
string myRadioText = String.Empty;

foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)    
{    
    RadioButton rd_CS = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rd_CS");

    if(rd_CS != null && rd_CS.Checked)
    {
        myRadioText = rd_CS.Text;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `Request.Form["rdGroup"]` to get the value.

If you want to get it in the context of the data list, then that's not possible with the current code. You need to add `runat="server"` to the radio button, then you can loop though the items and use the `Find` method to get a reference to the radio button control.

Comment: can you show me how to get checked value of radio button in datalist ?

Comment: @AnhNguyen: That's what I tried to do. Do you have a question in the context of the answer that I gave you?

Comment: @@Guffa: I got the solution using radio button in datalist instead of using the type input as code above but i still have a problem when trying to get the value of checked radio button. It's good if you can give me a sample code for getting the value of checked radio button in datalist. THank.

Comment: @AnhNguyen: A radio button control is always a server control. You need to add `runat="server"` to the HTML element to make it a server control, so that you can reach it in the server code. Otherwise it will just be a part of a string in a `LiteralControl` inside the item.

Comment: @@Guffa I edited code above. Can you check it again and answer the question in my second comment ? It would be great if you can give me a sample code. Thank.